# Changes in root .htaccess file not reflecting in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, url-rewrite, htaccess

I am using `Magento 2.1.`

I am trying to add a rewrite rule in `.htaccess` file for url's starting with `index.php?route=`. to be replaced with the query string.

> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^index.php?route=.+$ [NC]
>   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%{QUERY_STRING}\? [R=301,L]

But this url rewrite rule is not getting reflected in my site.

Am I editing the right file`(root/.htaccess)`.?

Please suggest a solution to my problem.

Comment: Silly question here, but Nginx? Apache?  What versions?

Answer (score 1):

Check if mod_rewrite is enabled on your server. That can be done by reading the phpinfo(); from a script on your server.

Use the below code in .htaccss

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Other way is

1. Log-in Magento Admin
2. Go to Stores-> Configuration -> Web
3. From Search Engine Optimisation tab Use Web Server Rewrites select YES.
4. Make sure your Secure and Unsecure base urls should end with “/”.

Remove cache and check.

Comment: I have ensured Server Rewrites is  selected YES and ensured Secure and Unsecure urls end with '/'. But still it is not working. Is it that I am in developer mode.?Should I be changing that.According to your Rewrite rule  "my_url/index.php/" should ideally go to "my_url write". Cleared cache,still not working..

Answer (score 1):

First, `QUERY_STRING` is everything after the question mark, so it should be `^route=.+$`  instead of `^index.php?route=.+$`. If you want to test for `index.php` as well, use a second condition with `REQUEST_URI`.

So instead of

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^index.php?route=.+$ [NC]
```

it would be

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^route=.+$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^index.php$ [NC]
```

Second, the rewrite rule would rewrite `/index.php?route=x` to `/route=x`. Is that really what you want? In case you actually need `/x`, use pattern matching:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^route=(.+)$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^index.php$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1\? [R=301,L]
```

`%1` matches the first sub-pattern in `RewriteCond`, just as `$1` matches the first sub-pattern in `RewriteRule`.